# "Cannot switch to old mode now" - Node.JS apn module error in tls.connect function

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to implement Node.JS apn module to connect to APNS (Apple Push Notification service) to push notification to iPhone devices from the Node server (using ExpressJS) hosted on Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04. I am getting this error:

```
"Error: Cannot switch to old mode now.",
"    at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:720:11)",
"    at ReadStream.Readable.resume (_stream_readable.js:705:3)",
"    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/usemebeta/routes/message.js:101:48)",
"    at TLSSocket.g (events.js:186:14)",
"    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:97:17)",
"    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:579:16)",
"    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:97:17)",
"    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:198:8)"
```

when I call the apn module function to push notification.
However when I do the same thing in a function written in a file and execute that file, then it works just fine. Please help. How should I go about fixing the problem?

Comment: Show the relevant code, so that we can reproduce and correct the error.

Comment: Also what version of Node.js are you using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update**: The behavior described below may have changed since this answer was originally written; as of `0.12.3`, the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_stream_readable) suggest that you can now switch back and forth between *paused* (new) and *flowing* (old) mode, and that streams start out in *paused* mode.
Also, "old" mistakenly suggests a deprecated way of doing things, but while the flowing mode came first, both are supported and have their uses.

---

I don't have a specific answer, but a general explanation:

The short of it: **old code that calls `.resume()` or `.pause()` on readable streams can break on node `0.10` and higher.**

The long of it:
You see this error on node `0.10` or higher when a readable stream has been initialized to use the **new, *paused* mode** (based on the `readable` event) and an attempt is later made to switch to the **old, *flowing* mode** (based on the `data` event), which is implicitly attempted when you call `.resume()` or `.pause()` - see the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_class_stream_readable).

Setting up a `readable` event may not even be directly involved.
For instance, it seems that using the `.pipe()` method now implicitly switches to the new, paused mode, so a subsequent `.resume()` call would trigger this error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the 'correct' way to fix the issue, but it worked for me. (You'll need to have [brew](http://brew.sh/))

1. `brew uninstall node`
2. `brew install nvm`
3. copy this into your shell config (in my case .zshrc)

`export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

4. `nvm install iojs`