# Is it possible to forward a stream from one function to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, form-data, busboy

Please have a look at the following sample code.

As you can see, it uses [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) to parse incoming form data and write incoming files to disc.
Let's assume these are just image files because my sample code makes use of imgur.com. (a content-length header doesn't need to be sent)
The imgurUpload() function makes use of [node-form-data](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data)

Is it somehow possible to stream the image files additionally, without the need to buffer them complete, to imgur.com? (to the imgurUpload() function and use it within node-form-data?)

Server / listener:

```
var http = require('http'),
  Busboy = require('busboy'),
  FormData = require('form-data'),
  fs = require('fs')

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    var busboy = new Busboy({
      headers: req.headers
    })
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      //pipe the stream to disc
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('1st-' + filename))
      //pipe the stream a 2nd time
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('2nd-' + filename))

      /* how to connect things together? */
    })
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Connection': 'close'
      })
      res.end("upload complete")
    })
    return req.pipe(busboy)
  } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html')
    stream.pipe(res)
  }
}).listen(80, function() {
  console.log('listening for requests')
})
```

HTML test form (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample function that submits an image file to imgur.com:

```
function imgurUpload(stream) {

  var form = new FormData()
  //form.append('Filedata', fs.createReadStream('test.jpg'))

  form.append('Filedata', /* how to connect things together? */X )
  form.submit('http://imgur.com/upload', function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err

    var body = ''
    res.on('data', function(chunk) { body += chunk })
    res.on('end', function() { console.log('http://imgur.com/' + JSON.parse(body).data.hash) })
  })
}
```

Update (regarding mscdex answer)

```
_stream_readable.js:748
    throw new Error('Cannot switch to old mode now.');
          ^
Error: Cannot switch to old mode now.
    at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:748:11)
    at FileStream.Readable.pause (_stream_readable.js:739:3)
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (\path\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:35:12)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (\path\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:30)
    at FormData.append (\path\node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:43:3)
    at imgurUpload (\path\app.js:54:8)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (\path\app.js:21:4)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:106:17)
    at Busboy.emit (\path\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (\path\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:205:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append Readable streams as shown in `node-form-data`'s readme. So this:

```
form.append('Filedata', stream);
```

should work just fine.

Then in your `file` event handler:

```
imgurUpload(file);
```

Comment: I already tried it this way but ran into an error (updated my question and added the error log). I did not note the "Cannot switch to old mode now" before. I looked it up
and found this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181116/4121003) - so it should work, but it isn't because a module is still using the old stream interface which is causing problems?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the `form-data` and/or `combined-stream` modules.