# How to pause nodejs flowing stream when destination is full

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

```
$ node --version
v0.10.29
```

Similar to ["Cannot switch to old mode now" - Node.JS apn module error in tls.connect function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306954/cannot-switch-to-old-mode-now-node-js-apn-module-error-in-tls-connect-functi) I'm getting a "Cannot switch to old mode now" error thrown when pausing a readable stream (in this case a HTTP response/[IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.29/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage))

```
_stream_readable.js:732
    throw new Error('Cannot switch to old mode now.');
          ^
Error: Cannot switch to old mode now.
    at emitDataEvents (_stream_readable.js:732:11)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.pause (_stream_readable.js:723:3)
```

The IncomingMessage has XML in the body which I'm piping in to a [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/) handler.  The handler then writes output to a [PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.29/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream which is piped to some destination.  Reading the [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.29/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) on `readable.pause()` and `readable.resume()` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Is there something about flowing streams that I'm missing, or am I implementing the wrong pattern below?

```
function wrapStream(incoming) {
  var dest = new PassThrough();
  dest.setEncoding("utf8");

  dest.on("drain", function () {
    incoming.resume();
  });

  var saxStream = sax.createStream(true, {});

  saxStream.print = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

    /*
     * It's my understanding that if the dest stream is full,
     * we should pause the IncomingMessage
     * until the dest drains.
     */
    if (!dest.write.apply(dest, args)) {
      // throws error here.
      incoming.pause();
    }
  };

  /*
   * Attach handlers to saxStream here.
   * They use the print() function to write data to dest.
   */

  saxStream.on("end", function() {
    dest.end();
  });

  incoming.pipe(saxStream);

  return dest;
}

var output = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/test.xml");

http.get(url, function(res) {
  var saxStream = wrapStream(res);

  saxStream.pipe(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streams embed a mechanism named back pressure. Piping a stream to another automatically take care of when the destination stream is busy. Except if you use old streams (node 0.8) but i assume it is not the case.

You should only do `req.pipe(saxStream)`.